# Cannot perform operation because childrenKeyPath is nil

Tags: objective-c, macos, crash, osx-lion, nstreecontroller

Why do I get this crash error when I try to insert a child into my `NSTreeController`?

```
NSTreeController *tree = [NSTreeController new];
NSTreeNode *node1 = [NSTreeNode treeNodeWithRepresentedObject:@{ @"type": @"shirt" }];

// The below method causes mysterious crash
[tree insertObject:node1 atArrangedObjectIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:0]];
```

**Xcode says:**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '[object class: NSMutableDictionary] Cannot perform operation because childrenKeyPath is nil'
>       ***

Why is causing this error? What is childrenKeyPath and why do I need it (I'm not using interface builder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made several mistakes here. You should not insert instances of type `NSTreeNode` into an `NSTreeController` with `insertObject`. You use `insertObject` to insert a model object, at which point an `NSTreeNode` will be **automatically** created for it.

Also, in your model object, you need to have a property or key which is set as an `NSMutableArray`. Then, before you insert any model objects, you set the `childrenKeyPath` property of `NSTreeController` to equal the name of that property or key.

This is because `NSTreeController` and `NSTreeNode` are not designed to hold data or child objects themselves, but act as a simple but helpful "map" for the models **you've** created and retained.

I hope this information helps others because the rest of StackOverflow was oddly silent about it...